# how to make event in js

Tags: javascript

```
chaychu = document.getElementById('chaychu');
chaychu.onMouseOver ="chaychu.stop";
```

How to make this code works- what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap it in function body:

```
chaychu = document.getElementById('chaychu');
chaychu.onmouseover = function(){
    // your code here....
};
```

If there is a function already there, you should do this instead:

```
chaychu = document.getElementById('chaychu');
chaychu.onmouseover = functionName;
```

Comment: `onmouseover` is not camel cased!